# Read only file system error (EFS as persistent storage in EKS)

Tags: airflow, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

```
----Storages files----
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
    name: aws-efs
provisioner: aws.io/aws-efs
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: efs-claim
namespace: dev
annotations:  
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "aws-efs"
spec:
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
        requests:
            storage: 20Gi

--------Deployment file--------------------
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: efs-provisioner
  namespace: dev
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: efs-provisioner
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["persistentvolumes"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "delete"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["persistentvolumeclaims"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "update"]
- apiGroups: ["storage.k8s.io"]


resources: ["storageclasses"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["events"]
  verbs: ["create", "update", "patch"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: efs-provisioner
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: efs-provisioner
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: efs-provisioner
  namespace: dev

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: leader-locking-efs-provisioner
  namespace: dev
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["endpoints"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: leader-locking-efs-provisioner
  namespace: dev
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: leader-locking-efs-provisioner
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: efs-provisioner
  namespace: dev

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: efs-provisioner
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: efs-provisioner
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: efs-provisioner
    spec:
      serviceAccount: efs-provisioner
      containers:
      - name: efs-provisioner
        image: quay.io/external_storage/efs-provisioner:latest
        env:
        - name: FILE_SYSTEM_ID
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: efs-provisioner-config
              key: file.system.id
        - name: AWS_REGION
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: efs-provisioner-config
              key: aws.region
        - name: DNS_NAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: efs-provisioner-config
              key: dns.name
              optional: true
        - name: PROVISIONER_NAME
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: efs-provisioner-config
              key: provisioner.name
        volumeMounts:
        - name: pv-volume
          mountPath: /efs-mount
      volumes:
      - name: pv-volume
        nfs:
          server: <File-system-dns>
          path: /

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: efs-provisioner-config
  namespace: dev
data:
  file.system.id: <File-system-id>
  aws.region: us-east-2
  provisioner.name: aws.io/aws-efs
  dns.name: ""


------release file----
apiVersion: helm.fluxcd.io/v1
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: airflow
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    flux.weave.works/automated: "true"
spec:
  releaseName: airflow-dev
  chart:
    repository: https://airflow.apache.org
    name: airflow
    version: 1.6.0
  values:
    fernetKey: <fernet-key>
    defaultAirflowTag: "2.3.0"
    env:
      - name: "AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_IN_IMAGE"
        value: "False"
      - name: "AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__NAMESPACE"
        value: "dev"
        value: "apache/airflow"
      - name: "AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG"
        value: "latest"
      - name: "AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__RUN_AS_USER"
        value: "50000"
      - name: "AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES"
        value: "False"
    executor: "KubernetesExecutor"
    dags:
      persistence:
        enabled: true
        size: 20Gi
        storageClassName: aws-efs
        existingClaim: efs-claim
        accessMode: ReadWriteMany
      gitSync:
        enabled: true
        repo: git@bitbucket.org: <git-repo>
        branch: master
        maxFailures: 0
        subPath: ""
        sshKeySecret: airflow-git-private-dags
        wait: 30
```

---

When im going to the scheduler pod, and going to directory /opt/airflow/dags$ , im get the read only file system error. But when i did "df -h", i can see that the file system is mounted on the pod. But i get read only error.

Kubectl get pv -n dev
This gives me the PV has "RWX" access and it shows that it has been mounted to my airflow trigger and airflow scheduler pods